# Разделение строки на список по 3 элемента в Python

Tags: python, строки, список, текст

При написании решении проблемы возникла необходимость данного навыка

```
string = "abcacbcab"
```

Нужно разделить эту строку на такой список:

```
final = ["abc","acb","cab"]
```

Я пробовал через обнаружение элемента в списке, но если к примеру искать 
"bca" то он его выдаст два раза, а мне этого не нужно

Comment: по каким критериям разбивать? просто по 3 символа?

Comment: Да, нужно просто в список через каждые 3 разделять строку

Comment: `[s[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(s), 3)]`

Comment: спасибо за короткое и ясное решение. Очень пригодилось

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Создание списка из списков по 3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/629246/23044)

Answer (score 3):

```
s = "abcacbcab"
print([s[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(s), 3)])
# ["abc","acb","cab"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно регуляркой разделить:

```
import re

items = re.findall(r'.{3}', "abcacbcab")
print(items)  # ['abc', 'acb', 'cab']
```

но такая регулярка будет искать только по 3 элемента, если попадется меньше, например, если длина строки не кратна 3, тогда оставшиеся элементы не попадут в результат.

---

По умолчанию `.` (точка) в регулярном выражении не ищет переводы на новую строку (`\n`), чтобы это исправить нужно указывать флаг `re.DOTALL`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'.{3}', "ab\ncd\nef\n", flags=re.DOTALL)
['ab\n', 'cd\n', 'ef\n']
```

Comment: точка новую строку не ищет по умолчанию. Нужно `re.DOTALL` флаг включить: `re.findall(r'(?s).{3}', "ab\ncd\nef\n")`

Comment: всегда удивляло такое поведение, ведь `.` говорит найди все символы, но потом оказывается, что все кроме \n